# tracing your python packets over the network

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Well, it's nothing much to present but, I wanted to make my cellphone and PC somehow connected, and at very first steps of research, I made these VERY SIMPLE tests:

```
#this is for the udp client file

import socket as soc
import os

server = "192.167.1.4"
serverPort = 12000
value = 0
sockobj = soc.socket(soc.AF_INET, soc.SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    message = 'This is my secret message: '
    message += input("Enter your message: ")
    data = message.encode(encoding="UTF-8")
    sockobj.sendto(data, (server, serverPort))
    if not value:
        # os.system("traceroute 192.168.1.4")
        value += 1
        import time
        time.sleep(5)
        print("sleep ended")
    message, address = sockobj.recvfrom(2048)
    print("I got", message.decode())
sockobj.close()
```

__

```
and this is for the udp server file  



import socket as soc
import time
server = ''
serverPort = 12000
sockobj = soc.socket(soc.AF_INET, soc.SOCK_DGRAM)
sockobj.bind((server, serverPort))
while True:
    message, clientaddress = sockobj.recvfrom(2048)
    print("I got the client's address as: ", clientaddress)
    print("I got the message")
    print("...modifying, this might take time")
    message = message.decode().upper()
    data = ("Server: {} data with {} length".format(message, len(message.split()))).encode(encoding="UTF-8")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    sockobj.sendto(data,clientaddress)
    print("SENT!")
sockobj.close()
```

I currently have QPython installed on my android device and am running the server file from there. And the devices do connect and communicate!!

**So, at this point**, I wanted to see how the packets travelled from my PC to cell phone, running traceroute from terminal was no use, connection was refused to my cell phone's local IP: `192.167.1.4`, I thought so I'd do a system call from the **udp client** script, but no luck from there either. **I guess is that** the packets would bounce from my PC to router to my cell phone, but, that's just a guess. So, How can I trace my packets for this script?

Answer (score 0):

Probably better served as a comment. But seeing as their has been almost no activity on this post, I figured to just post it as an answer.

Have you tried using: https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/dnac-python-path-trace

It does pretty much what you seem to be looking for. You can look at the code to get an idea of how it works.